# SQL Server dynamic Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which works fine

```
SELECT
   Product, Description,
   Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = ’01.2011’ THEN [A_Sales]  END) AS [A_salesFeb],
   Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = ’05.2011’ THEN [A_Sales]  END) AS [A_salesMay],
   Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = ’01.2011’ THEN [B_Sales]  END) AS [B_salesFeb],
   Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = ’05.2011’ THEN [B_Sales]  END) AS [B_salesMay],
 FROM tblSales
 GROUP BY Product, Description
```

Now I need to make it dynamic at the level Datum = ‘ ’. Let say I now have 08.2012 and 04.2013
It should look through and do the matching.
So I changed it to the below query **but it isn’t working**. I getting the wrong figures

```
SELECT
    Product, Description,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = Datum  THEN [A_Sales]  END) AS [A_salesFeb],
    Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = Datum  THEN [A_Sales]  END) AS [A_salesMay],
    Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = Datum THEN [B_Sales]  END) AS [B_salesFeb],
    Sum(CASE WHEN Datum = Datum  THEN [B_Sales]  END) AS [B_salesMay],
FROM tblSales
GROUP BY Product, Description
```

Data Sample: I have 12 Tables and I want the user to be able to select any two tables dynamically/alternatively and then do a comparisim. What I have now is static. Something like this:
[Sample data](http://p40i.imgup.net/AA02fdd0.PNG?l=de)

Comment: Add some sample data, and tell us more than "it's not working".

Comment: this would be solvable if you can provide some sample data with desired output.

Comment: The month column should be Datum

Comment: I am assuming the datum field is the date in this format mm.yyyy? The column name needs to match the month/year on the output?

Comment: Look at your case expression. What are you trying to do. This is like saying "Case when 1 = 1 then"

Comment: As I wrote it's working when Datum is staticc but what if a user chose two different tables where the Datum is for example. 08.2012 and 01.2013? That why my second query is Datum = Datum but the returned results are not correct. Is the a different way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data and desired resultset in your example data - this is the query I would write:

```
select Datum, Product, sum(FebSales13.A_sales) as A_SalesFeb,
sum(FebSales13.B_sales) as B_SalesFeb, sum(MaySales12.A_sales) as A_SalesMay, 
sum(MaySales12.B_sales) as B_SalesMay
from   
   ( select Datum,  Product, A_sales, B_sales
   from FebSales13 ) FebSales13
inner join 
   ( select Datum,  Product, A_sales, B_sales
   from MaySales13 ) MaySales13
on FebSales13.Datum = MaySales12.Datum
and  FebSales13.Product = MaySales12.Product
group by Datum, Product
```